# Is there any tool to easily blur a picture?

Tags: post-processing, blur

Hey I'm new on that part of the stackexchange and I'm wondering if you guys know a tool to generate a blurry version of a picture, an online tool would be perfect.

I don't know anything about design tools such as photoshop, and I only need to blur a picture.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: to create a blurry background for a web application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Pixlr Express](http://pixlr.com/express/) and pick Adjustment > Blur.

Comment: Exactly what I needed